# How to set range of separate cells in DataSeriesValues PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I can't make barchart with PhpSpreadsheet. I need to add to DataSeriesValues range of separate cells

This works fine

```
 $xAxisTickValues = [
new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$A$1:$G$1', null, 4), 
 ];
```

But i need something like this

```
 $xAxisTickValues = [
  new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$A$1,Worksheet!$C$1,Worksheet!$E$1,Worksheet!$G$1', null, 4),
 ];
```